# How to get time and value from MySQL into Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, highcharts

I have a mysql table with a timestamp and temperature fields.  I am getting the data into json format but the chart is not drawing the data.  Can anyone provide me with any guidance as I'm having difficulty debugging it.

The json is:

```
[[["01:00","6.20"],["02:00","6.10"],["03:00","5.60"],["04:00","4.20"],["05:00","3.60"],["06:00","3.50"],["07:00","3.50"],["08:00","4.30"],["09:00","5.40"]]]
```

The javascript is:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'spline'
    },
    series: [{}]
};

$.getJSON('temp.json', function(data) {
    options.series[0].data = data;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});

});
```

I have the data line working with the following:

json

```
[["01:00",6.20],["02:00",6.10],["03:00",5.60],["04:00",4.20],["05:00",3.60],["06:00",3.50],["07:00",3.50],["08:00",4.30],["09:00",5.40],["10:00",7.00]]
```

javascript

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Temperature'
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Todays temperature trend'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            hour: '%H:%M'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Time'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (c)'
        }},
        tooltip: {
           valueSuffix: ' c'
       },
    series: [{}]
};

$.getJSON('temp.json', function(data) {
    options.series[0].data = data;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});

});
```

The x axis is formatting as Jan '10, Feb '10 rather than 01:00 for the hour.  That seems to be my only remaining issue.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: That's as far as I've got.  I can't work out how to get the data series with only part of it from mySQL.  It's a confusion of echoed php in javascript loops in my head.

Comment: Did you google any examples?  googling "php highcharts" -> site with samples http://highcharts-mzm.rhcloud.com/ -> code for the site https://github.com/pesima/highcharts/tree/master/pie/data -> sample how to get code out of the database using php and format it to json https://github.com/pesima/highcharts/blob/master/pie/data/data-pie-chart.php and https://github.com/pesima/highcharts/blob/master/pie/pie-chart_1.php how to load the json data into piechart

Comment: I've updated the question with further information after I've tried using json

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use [Highcharts.dateFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Highcharts.dateFormat).

Below is example which i am using.

```
xAxis: [{
                    categories: categories,
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.value);
                        },
                        style: {
                            'font-size': '11px',
                        },
                    },
                    type: 'datetime',


       }],
```

Hope this will helpful to you.

Comment: That's helped a bit, now I have the x axis as a date axis but the data is still not populating so it doesn't seem to be getting it from the json.

Comment: you have problem on y axis data display ?

Comment: error on x axis value display right? Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: I now have a data line working, I had to remove the extra square brackets.  Y axis is all correct but x axis is not showing time as hour:minute but as 00:00:00.001, 00:00:00.002.  I guess there is a simple format tweak needed?

Comment: ["01:00","6.20"],["02:00","6.10"] you have store 01:00 , 02:00 in database?

Comment: It's stored as a timestamp in mySQL, I'm using date_format to extract only the time portion

Comment: don't use timeformat there .. Use timeformat as above my answer . Return complete date from there.

Comment: don't use timeformat there .. Use timeformat as above my answer . Return complete date from there.If you want only hour and minute to display into the x axis then use '%H-%M' in format . also i update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working.

Issues were the extra square brackets on the json and the "" round the temperature values.

Issue with the x axis as in the pointInterval being set to day rather than hour.

Working code below

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Temperature'
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Todays temperature trend'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            hour: '%H:%M'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Time'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (c)'
        }},
        tooltip: {
           valueSuffix: ' c'
       },
    series: [{name: 'Temperature', pointStart: Date.UTC(2017, 2, 17, 1),
    pointInterval: 3600 * 1000}]
};

$.getJSON('temp.json', function(data) {
    options.series[0].data = data;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});

});
```